# Obtaining Total value of votes using spatial join in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-join

I have been tasked with aggregating precinct level voting data upto the county level. I have both the layers and I used the spatial join tool to do the aggregation.

However, there is a complication. On using INTERSECT as MATCH OPTION, i dont get the total number of votes as some of the PRECINCT LINES CROSS THE COUNTY LINES.

I used several other MATCH OPTIONS but didn't get the required results. 
Please suggest which MATCH OPTION should i use in order to get the total value[image: Below is the image of the map i am working on. Take a look at the layers as well]

Comment: I suggest to use `match option` of `HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN` to insure that the cenroids of the Precinct polygon are inside the county boundary.